# Integration through a Rotated Square

Tags: definite-integrals, computational-geometry

I have a 2D square S.  S is described by s, the side length, theta, the angle it is rotated by, and **c**, the position of S's center.

There is an axis-aligned rectangle R that extends infinitely in the x direction.  The bottom of R has height 0, and the top of R has some height k.

I need to find the magnitude of the area this rotated square intersects with R.  I'm confident I could do this with some crufty logic and line-line intersections, but is there an elegant way to accomplish the same?